# How to toggle SVG circle with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm having a problem with my JavaScript code.

I want to show and hide two SVG circles when I click a button.

I don't seem to have any errors when I checked my console, but the button doesn't seem to work...

This is the code for the button, and I set the button id as "strike_btn", 
and the id for SVG circles as "strike"

Code:

```js
onload = function() {
  function changeStr() {
    var strike = document.getElementById('strike');
    if (strike.style.display === 'block') {
      strike.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  var strbutton = document.getElementById('strike_btn');
  strbutton.addEventListener('click', changeStr);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="strike_btn">Strike</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="abc">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 600 780">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill: white; stroke-width: 3; stroke: black"></rect>
        <rect x="21.5%" y="24.03846154%" width="56.6666667%" height="51.92307692%" style="fill: white; stroke-width: 2; stroke: black"></rect>
        <circle cx="-26.383257142857147%" cy="75.28764912669683%" r="4" fill="#1C6FA6"></circle>
        <circle cx="-28.12094285714285%" cy="52.508967516968326%" id ="strike" r="4" fill="#1C6FA6"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `circle#strike` element doesn't have a `display` property set. I think that's why your check doesn't pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the circles were not at all visible in the canvas.

Secondly the initial value is NOT set unless you set it

```js
var strike1, strike2;
function changeStr() {
  strike1.style.display = strike1.style.display === "none"?"block":"none";
  strike2.style.display = strike2.style.display === "none"?"block":"none";
}

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  strike1 = document.getElementById('strike1');
  strike2 = document.getElementById('strike2');
  strike1.style.display = "none";
  strike2.style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('strike_btn').addEventListener('click', changeStr);
})
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="strike_btn">Strike</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="abc">
      <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 180">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill: white; stroke-width: 3; stroke: black"></rect>
        <rect x="21.5%" y="24.03846154%" width="56.6666667%" height="51.92307692%" style="fill: white; stroke-width: 2; stroke: black"></rect>
        <circle cx="26.383257142857147%" cy="75.28764912669683%" id ="strike1" r="4" fill="#1C6FA6"></circle>
        <circle cx="28.12094285714285%" cy="52.508967516968326%" id ="strike2" r="4" fill="#1C6FA6"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! I could see the button didn't work when the circles were outside the rectangle box

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `style` attribute with block `style="display: block;"` for this to work (changed the x coordinates for the snippet because the circles were out of window bounds)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function changeStr() {
    var strike = document.getElementById('strike');
    if (strike.style.display === 'block') {
      strike.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  var strbutton = document.getElementById('strike_btn');
  strbutton.addEventListener('click', changeStr);
};
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="strike_btn">Strike</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="abc">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 600 780">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" style="fill: white; stroke-width: 3; stroke: black"></rect>
        <rect x="21.5%" y="24.03846154%" width="56.6666667%" height="51.92307692%" style="fill: white; stroke-width: 2; stroke: black"></rect>
        <circle cx="26.383257142857147%" cy="75.28764912669683%" r="4" fill="#1C6FA6"></circle>
        <circle cx="28.12094285714285%" cy="52.508967516968326%" id ="strike" r="4" fill="#1C6FA6" style="display: block;"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The display property of strike is probably not "block". Check what the computed display property is in the dev tools, or change that line to:

```
if (strike.style.display !== 'none') {
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add the second condition

```
if (strike.style.display === 'none') {
    strike.style.display = "block";  
}
```

or just an else like this:

```
if (strike.style.display === 'block') {
    strike.style.display = "none";
} else {
    strike.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Since the value initially is "" then this would mean the user has to click twice

Comment: So set it to 'none' at the begin